# Problem with binomial sumation

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to solve the following summation:

$\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} {M-1 \choose k} \alpha^{k} (1-\alpha)^{M-1-k} u(k)$

where:

$u(k) = 1$ , if $0 \le k < j$

$u(k) = (1-\frac{j}{k+1})$ , if $M-1 \ge k \ge j$

Is there a close expression for this summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a closed form (we see sums like this in binomial distributions), but we can put this into a slightly nicer form.

Write the sum as

$$\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} \binom{M-1}{k} \alpha^k (1-\alpha)^{M-1-k} + \sum_{k=j}^{M-1} \binom{M-1}{k} \alpha^k (1-\alpha)^{M-1-k} \left (1-\frac{j}{k+1}\right)$$

Note we can remove the one in the second term and get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} \binom{M-1}{k} \alpha^k (1-\alpha)^{M-1-k} - j \sum_{k=j}^{M-1} \binom{M-1}{k} \alpha^k (1-\alpha)^{M-1-k} \frac{1}{k+1}$$

Note that the first term is simply $(\alpha+1-\alpha)^{M-1} = 1$ by the binomial theorem.  Also note that

$$\frac{1}{k+1} \binom{M-1}{k} = \frac{1}{M} \binom{M}{k+1}$$

Then we may write the sum as

$$1-\frac{j}{M} \sum_{k=j}^{M-1} \binom{M}{k+1} \alpha^k (1-\alpha)^{M-1-k}$$